# Definability of set

Tags: logic, computability, first-order-logic

Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint sets definable (shouldn't be relevant, but I'm working in the standard model of natural numbers and the language of Peano) respectively with a formula $\varphi_A$ and $\varphi_B$, both with $n$ alternated quantifiers, the outermost being existential, and let $C=(A \cup B)^C$.

From the hypotheses it easily follows that $C^C$ is definable with a formula with $n$ alternated quantifiers, the outermost being existential.

Since $B=A^C\cap C^C$ I would like to show that either $A^C$ can be defined with a formula with $n$ alternated quantifiers, the outermost being existential, or both $B$ and $C^C$ can be defined using a formula with $n$ alternated quantifiers, the outermost being universal (or both the things).

Using the Arithmetical Hierarchy jargon, the same question can be phrased as: if $A,B \in \Sigma^0_n$ and $C=(A\cup B)^C$ can we conclude that either $A\in\Pi^0_n$ or $B,C^C\in\Pi^0_n$ (or both)?

Comment: Does $C^C$ denote the complement of $C$?

Comment: Yes, in general I used the superscript ${}^C$ for the complement

Comment: Thank you -- but then how are you concluding that $B=A^C\cap C^C?$  Since $C=(A \cup B)^C,$ we have $C^C=A\cup B,$ so $A^C \cap C^C = A^C \cap (A\cup B),$ which is $B \setminus A,$ not $B.$

Comment: Oh yes, you're perfectly right. My bad, I forgot to add the (crucial) part that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. Sorry for that, I edit the question.

Comment: The whole question makes more sense now!

Comment: Because $A$ and $B$ could both be $\Sigma^0_n$ complete, it's immediately possible for neither to be $\Pi^0_n$. There are $\Sigma^0_n$ complete sets for all $n > 0$, most notably $0^{(n)}$, the $n$th Turing jump of the empty set, by Post's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, here's a counterexample.

Let $X$ be a set of natural numbers that is recursively enumerable but not recursive.  (So $X$ is $\Sigma^0_1$ but not $\Pi^0_1.)$

Define $A = \lbrace 2n \mid n\in X \rbrace,$ and $B = \lbrace 2n+1 \mid n\in X \rbrace.$  Then $A$ and $B$ are also both $\Sigma^0_1$ but not $\Pi^0_1,$ which is enough to see that this is a counterexample.

By the way, $C^C = A \cup B$ is also $\Sigma^0_1$ (since both $A$ and $B$ are $\Sigma^0_1)$ but not $\Pi^0_1$ (since if it were $\Pi^0_1,$ it would then be recursive, which would imply that $X$ is recursive).